# R data.table create dummy column which map existed column

Tags: r, data.table, correlation

I want to create a dummy `numeric` column which map 1-1 with existed `character` column to run `correlation`

My table look like:

```
Code
US
UK
VN
US
VN
UK
```

I want to have new column `dummy` which map `US, UK, VN` to `1, 2, 3`

```
Code     dummy
US       1
UK       2
VN       3
US       1
VN       3
UK       2
```

Hope someone can help!

Comment: What did you try? Explain the part of code. So that people here can know where you are failing to get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done either by converting the `Code` column to `factor` class with `levels` specified as the `unique` elements of `Code` and convert it back to `numeric` and assign (`:=`) it to `dummy`

```
library(data.table)
DT[, dummy:=as.numeric(factor(Code, levels=unique(Code)))][]
#     Code dummy
#1:   US     1
#2:   UK     2
#3:   VN     3
#4:   US     1
#5:   VN     3
#6:   UK     2
```

Or use `match` between the 'Code' and `unique` elements of 'Code'

```
DT[, dummy:=  match(Code, unique(Code))]
```

Or `chmatch` from `data.table`

```
DT[, dummy:= chmatch(Code, unique(Code))]
```

Comment: I have checked 2 method and I found `match` method is much better

Answer (score 5):

Or you can simply use the built in `.GRP` function

```
DT[, dummy := .GRP, by = Code][]
#    Code dummy
# 1:   US     1
# 2:   UK     2
# 3:   VN     3
# 4:   US     1
# 5:   VN     3
# 6:   UK     2
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg, `match` from base R uses hash tables underneath. And from my benchmarks, it's quite efficient, but not faster than `chmatch` or dt's grouping..

Comment: @DavidArenburg the `system.time` is much better for `.GRP` compared to `chmatch` on a 1e6 dataset.